# Spring security: restful web services and maintaining user sessions

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-security, spring-rest

In a classical jsp or php application, user sessions can be maintained through below process
1) on first access to a resource, challenge user to authenticate using userid & password.
2) if the credential are correct, then successfully authenticate the user and create a session id
3) attach the sessionid to header and send response back to user with requested information.
4) on subsequent request from user, the server checks for a valid sessionid in the headers
5) if the sessionid is valid and not expired then there is no need for authentication and user is allowed to perform requested action.

The whole point above is for the user to enter credentials only once.

But how to achieve this in a rest full design, where resources are accessed through ajax/jquery call. Like with classical JSP, if I want the user to enter credentials only once how can this be achieved (at least I am not aware of how to passon header (i.e sessionid) to server with ajax requests)

I am using **spring restful web services** api with **spring security** - i.e delegating filter proxy (spring security filter chains) with basic authentication. And I want the user to enter his credentials only once to login and subsequent ajax request to restful resources on server should be automatically able to find out that the user recently signed in and should be allowed to perform the requested action on restful resource with the need to re-authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to configure `Spring Security`, so that is covers your `REST API`, here is one of the examples on how to do this - [Spring Security for a REST API](http://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security).

One of the ways to keep user authenticated is to store session id in cookies or any other storage, this way backend can verify it. On the backend side, the `REST API` should be stateless. So, the best way is to keep a session id in database in some sessions table (`Redis` is a usual solution for such cases).

If you'd like to design a `REST API`, I would send session id in headers as you've explained with each `AJAX` call. One API method should authenticate user and provide a token (or session id), which should be stored by the client somewhere (e.g. in cookies). All other methods should require it to be able to access a resource. When the user is logged out, this value should be erased and user shouldn't be able to access a resource.

Comment: this is very close to what i am expecting.  "I would send session id in headers as you've explained with each AJAX call."  any small code snippet of how to achieve this through ajax/jquery.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to provide code as the example will not be small enough. You just need to add it as a header in http request.